# php syntax for variable column name in query

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to pass the name of a column as a variable to a PHP database query.

the hard coded syntax works perfectly and is:
`select max([257612cr]) as price from Price_TekwaniPrice where customeraccount='DAY001'`

When I pass the variable I get error `trying to get property ofnon object`. my syntax is:

```
        $query = $this->db->query("
select max(['$product']) as price from Price where customeraccount='$customer'
      ");
```

I also tried:

```
        $query = $this->db->query("
select max(".$product.") as price from Price where customeraccount='$customer'
      ");
```

I have confirmed that the variables are being passed correctly. the syntax for `'$customer'` works perfectly so just passing the `$product` variable as a column name is proving cumbersome.

I am using php with codeigniter. any advice welcome.

Thanks as always,

Comment: Have you tried printing out the composed query string before passing it to the query() function to see if it matches what you expect? Have you tried running that printed query on the database manually?

Comment: The error message provided doesn't make sense for the code you provided unless `$this` is not an object.

Comment: Are you sure that `$product` is a string ? Isn't it an object, triggering some [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)  method when used in a concatenation context ?

Comment: yea, print_r($product); first

Comment: Thanks Tomas, unfortunately using codeigniter to call this php function. as such cnnot see the last query. any idea on what the syntax should be?

Comment: Thanks, $product definately a string. I cant quite view last executed query ot print the result as jquery is posting this information to a jquery function, not a new view. so printed php info wont be displayed.

Comment: any suggestions on what code should be based on this requirements? how would you pass the PHP variables to the query? `$query = $this->db->query("
select max(['$product']) as price from Price where customeraccount='$customer'
      ");`

Comment: What Tomas meant is : put you sql statement into a variable, display/log it and then use it for your query. eg. `$sql = 'select max() etc';` `echo $sql;` then `$query = $this->db->query($sql);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to concatenate a php variable when already opened double quotes try this

```
 $query = $this->db->query("
select max([$product]) as price from Price where customeraccount='$customer'
      ");
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->query("
select max($product) as price from Price where customeraccount='$customer'
      ");
```

While about the error you are getting is due i think  your database driver is not loaded first try to load database

`$this->load->database('default', TRUE);`

The best way to use CI's Active record you can do so

```
$this->db->select_max($product);
$this->db->where('customeraccount', $customer); 
$query = $this->db->get('Price');
```

See [**Active Record**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: How does that relate to the `trying to get property of non-object` error?

Comment: some advice about SQL injection? is $product sanitized?

Comment: Hi, still error: `Trying to get property of non-object` $product def not being passed correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @Smudger See my updated answer regarding the Active record usage